# Is there a function to split data into test and train in tensorflow 2.0 similar to test_train_split of sklearn.model_selection?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow2.0

I am using tensorflow 2.4.1. I want to split my data into training ,test and validation sets. I can use sklearn.model_selection for splitting my data. However I want to know if there is a similar api in tensorflow ?

Comment: What's wrong with having the sklearn splitting function? Do you need more features? Do you need to drop it from your dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a functionality in tensorflow itself